# Java Area of DrawnLine

Tags: java, area

Java seems not to have any method of obtaining pixels that have been drawn to. I know there are certain algorithms java uses in order to draw geometric primitives to the screen. What I am trying to do is receive these pixels that are drawn to and place them into an area. The reason I am doing this is because I would like to clip the area drawn to so that I can animate and draw texturepaint to the specified region. My program uses abstract actions to dynamically change the dimensions of the texturepaint. For instance, I have a certain operation in the abstract action to make an ocean like texture paint rise and lower in tide.

Edit : My TextureAnimation class quickly changes the type of texturepaint and repaints the component that is targeted. If I were to paint without clipping it would just flood the entire world with my texturepaint, but with clipping I could tell java to repaint the entire rectangle with the set clipping area and it would repaint the texturepaint only to the specified region.

Solved : Although I still cannot receive the area of the pixels drawn to I can still capture collision detection using a parallel color map. I found that if I do this combined with setting the graphics composite i.e. Graphics2D.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcIn). Calling this method allowed me to paint only to the non-transparent pixels of the BufferedImage. I hope this helps others who have run into similar problems

```
public class TextureAnimation implements ActionListener {

private Action behavior;
private BufferedImage image;
private Component host;

private TexturePaint paint;
private Timer t;

public int x;
public int y;

public TextureAnimation(Action a, BufferedImage i, Component c){

    behavior = a;
    image = i;
    host = c;

    paint = new TexturePaint(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.getWidth(),    image.getHeight()));

    t = new Timer(300, this);
    t.setInitialDelay(0);


}

public void playAnimation(){

    t.start();

}

public void delayAnimation(int ms_delay){

    t.setInitialDelay(ms_delay);
    t.restart();

}

public void setIntervalDelay(int ms_delay){

    t.setDelay(ms_delay);

}

public void setTilePosition(int x, int y){

    paint = new TexturePaint(image, new Rectangle(Gscale.setX(x), Gscale.setY(y), Gscale.setWidth(image.getWidth()), Gscale.setHeight(image.getHeight())));

}

public TexturePaint animatedPaint(){

    return paint;

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    behavior.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, null));
    host.repaint(0,0, host.getWidth(), host.getHeight());
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your code and what does it produce?

Comment: @La-comadreja That was a terrible reason to downvote. The question simply asks if a method exists that does what he wants. That seems like a solid question. What do you hope to see in his code?

Comment: I would like to see what he tried to do and how he's approaching the operation.

Comment: @La-comadreja In other words I would like to take on anything I draw to the component as an area so that I can clip it for repainting the texturepaint.

Comment: So for illustrating, you *roughly* want to 1. draw something, for example with `g.drawRect(x,y,w,h)`, and 2. obtain all pixels that have been affected by this drawing operation as an `Area` object. Is that right? IF this is what you meant: This might be a hassle. You should consider using `Shape` objects for drawing, as they can easily be converted into an `Area` object directly...

Comment: @Marco13 Thanks for the advice. I found sort of a way around it by using AlphaComposite.SrcIn instead of using clipping. It seems to work as long as I use separate bufferedImages for each layer of animated texturepaint that I use.